# Extract specific pages into PDF file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract a set of pages from a pdf that contains several sets. Such conjunctions are distinguished by submissions. Inside the pdf has the following information ...
1 - Set of 3 shipments
Page: 1/continued
Page: 2/continued
Page: 3/last

2 - Set of 2 shipments
Page: 1/continued
Page: 2/last

2 - Set of 1 shipping
Page 1/1

This is to speed up my service, since I have to separate these sets manually.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import re

output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("pdf_teste.PDF", "rb"))
totalPages = input1.getNumPages()
print ("total pages to process:" +str(totalPages))

for i in range(totalPages):
    p = i
    print ("processing page %s" %str(i))
    output.addPage(input1.getPage(p))
    p = input1.getPage(p).extractText()#extract text to search for identifier
    pr = re.search("Diretor", p)#search for the identifier; to be replaced with a list
    #if there's a match, do work
    if pr:
        outputStream = open("test"+str(i)+".pdf", "wb")
        output.write(outputStream)
        outputStream.close()
        print ('match on page %s' %str(i))
        print ('\n')
```

This code almost does what I want.
He divides the first set, but from the second it repeats the first set and the second set. But I want a pdf for each set.